# VBS - batch prefix files with date

Tags: vbscript

Suppose I have the files as below:

```
c:\tmp\
       |_ tony.txt
       |_ peter.txt
       |_ mary.txt
       |_ may.txt
```

How can I write the .vbs file to batch append TODAY date to the front of the file?
The result should look like:

```
c:\tmp\
       |_ 20110630_tony.txt
       |_ 20110630_peter.txt
       |_ 20110630_mary.txt
       |_ 20110630_may.txt
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would this get you started?  You'll probably want to add some error checking...

```
Option Explicit

Const FOLDER_PATH = "C:\TMP"
Dim fso, folder, file, newFileName

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(FOLDER_PATH)
For Each file In folder.Files
    newFileName = Year(Now) & Right("0" & Month(Now),2) & Right("0" & Day(Now),2) & "_" & file.Name
    fso.MoveFile file.Path,file.ParentFolder.Path & "\" & newFileName
Next
```